# What is the best way to select multiple random results from table with different where cases

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have this query, which is nothing special but I don't think it's efficient at all. I want to select from a single table random rows with different where cases. So the result should be 1 random row with the specific type for each select like shown in the queries. Some of the "type" values can be the same but they should still return random result.

```
Select * from fruits where type = 1 order by RAND() limit 1
Select * from fruits where type = 1 order by RAND() limit 1
Select * from fruits where type = 3 order by RAND() limit 1
Select * from fruits where type = 4 order by RAND() limit 1
Select * from fruits where type = 4 order by RAND() limit 1
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql but it doesn't matter as long as I understand how to do it even if it's not a mysql example

Comment: Do you need to simply union the queries?

Comment: Not union, i just don't see executing 5 queries every time efficient, so I just want to convert it to 1 query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function with `ORDER BY RAND()` to assign a random ordering for the rows of each `type`.
Then select the number of rows you want for each `type`.
This will work in MySql:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY RAND()) rn 
  FROM fruits 
  WHERE type IN (1, 3, 4)
) t
WHERE rn <= CASE type
  WHEN 1 THEN 2 -- 2 rows for type = 1
  WHEN 3 THEN 1 -- 1 row  for type = 3
  WHEN 4 THEN 2 -- 2 rows for type = 4
END
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42b1cae85e275e7dc50de41cdf8e1cb7).

Comment: I am currently using mysql, but plan to migrate to sql anyway so will setup a test server and test it tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: @V.Rashkov For SQL Server the only difference would be to change RAND() to NEWID(): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47caddbbead39ec40a6dc7b1a5a4f6bc

Answer (score 1):

I would express this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t 
     ) t join
     (select 1 as type, 2 as n union all
      select 3 as type, 1 as n union all
      select 4 as type, 2 as n
     ) x
     using (type)
where x.n <= seqnum
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `Postgres`:

```
select distinct on (type) type, *
from like_this
where type in ( 1,2,3,4,5)
order by type, random()
```

Comment: Need to check how to convert to mysql, but just a question will this work if I want to return also something like (1,1,2,3,3,5) . some of the results to have the same type but still they should be picked random? It won't group them right ?

Comment: no this is showing 1 random row per each type